# I used to use a tool for zsh but I forgot what it was

Tags: zsh, command-history

I use ctrl-r frequently on zsh to iterate over previous commands. I used to have this 'modification' where ctrl-r actually displayed matches for me as I was typing the search string.

Does anyone know what extension / tool this is? Currently, ctrl-r only shows a single match under my cursor at a time. I'd like to see multiple matches and then navigate over them to select one.

I use zsh, zprezto, and macOS.

Comment: fuzzy auto-completion (fzf) https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `zsh-autocomplete` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) can do that:
[image: live history search]